# Magento - How to add multiple modules under the same label in Admin?

Tags: php, xml, magento

I created three modules and all of them can be configured through admin panel, Configuration.
How can I set only one label for all these modules?
I think that it's a system.xml setting:

First module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<tabs>
    <addthis translate="label" module="share">
        <label>Label</label>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
    </addthis>
</tabs>
<sections>
...
```

Second one:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<tabs>
    <slider translate="label">
        <label>Label</label>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
    </slider>
</tabs>
<sections>
...
```

Third One:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<tabs>
    <store translate="label">
        <label>Label</label>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
    </store>
</tabs>
<sections>
...
```

Anticipated thanks.

Comment: try to use the same *element name* (instead of `addthis`,`slider`,`store`)

Comment: Very good idea, but these are diffrent modules and I just want to get all together under a label. Hope there are other ways of doing this.

Comment: I understood that, but you still can use the same element name.

Comment: right now on app/code/community I got three modules, I guess the solution will be to create a single module, I can't make them work on the same label/tab in other way

Comment: Did you try it? Because no.

Comment: the problem was the line: <tab>ritchey</tab>, this was diffrent and now two of the plugins are on the same label and a diffrent one is on a diffrent label

Comment: Take a look here: http://pastebin.com/DKa537dV , First two modules appear under the same label, and the third one appear on a diffrent label. Can't see the problem.

Comment: tabs/ritchey is only needed once.

Comment: So I removed tabs/ritchey from the second and the third modules and it's still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to set same tab for all modules:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<tabs>
<name translate="label" module="share">
    <label>Label</label>
    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
</name>
</tabs>
...
<tab>name</tab>
```

Where the tab name is "name" for all modules and the Label can be diffrent for each module.

Thanks to [fab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/664108/fab) for finding the solution.